# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, apache-poi

I have added 3rd party Apache POI JAR in my Flutter Android app to achieve some features. But after adding POI library when I try to run getting following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'poi-4.1.2.jar (project :poi-4.1.2)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/chandra/Developer/globaldata/android/poi-4.1.2/poi-4.1.2.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, was able to fix it by using [andruhon](https://github.com/andruhon)'s repo solution.
Basically, the dependency will be substituted with `.jar` files placed in you project's `libs` folder.

1. Go to the [repo](https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx) and download the `.jar` files (at the time of writing the message they are called `poi-3.12-android-a.jar` and `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar`)
2. Place the files in your project's `libs` folder (`<project_name>/app/libs`)
3. Make sure your `build.gradle` includes `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`